# Android App working on Emulator but crashes at launch on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have read through thousands of pages and have yet to find a solution. I am relatively new at Android Development and this is the first time I am deploying any kind of app on a mobile device and my problem is that the application runs on my emulator flawlessly, but on my device it crashes at launch. I have kind of pin pointed the error as to being related to accessing data from the database I am packaging with the app.

Basically, my first activity calls a function to retrieve airport codes from the DB. It gets to the function in my DBContext file and returns an error:

```
    0java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maziz.POS/com.maziz.POS.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    1at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    2at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    3at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    4at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    5at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    6at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    7at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    8at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    9at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    10at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    11at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    13at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.getAirportCodes(POSContext.java:178)
    14at com.maziz.POS.Login.onCreate(Login.java:29)
    15at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    16at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    17... 11 more
```

FirstActivity: Login.java

```
    package com.maziz.POS;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler;
    public class Login extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Creates instance of all Global Vars
    // GlobalVars gv = (GlobalVars) getApplicationContext();
    BugSenseHandler.setup(this, "00728e23");
    GlobalVars gv = (GlobalVars) getApplicationContext();
    Cursor cc = gv.db.getAirportCodes();

    while(cc.moveToNext())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cc.getColumnCount(); i++) {
              gv.Airport_Codes.add(cc.getString(i));
            }
    }

    final EditText txtUserID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userID = txtUserID.getText().toString();
            String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

            if (checkLogin(userID, password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        FASelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                ad.setMessage("Login Not Successful");
                ad.setNeutralButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Re-Enter Your Info...",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                ad.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public boolean checkLogin(String u, String p) {
    GlobalVars gv = (GlobalVars) getApplicationContext();

    Cursor c = gv.db.getUser(u);

    User temp = new User();
    temp.setUserID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Employee_ID")));
    temp.setPassword(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Password")));
    boolean exists = false;

    if(c == null)
        return false;

    if (temp.UserID.equalsIgnoreCase(u)) {
        if (temp.Password.equals(p)) {
            gv.user = temp;

            gv.PK_Login_Log = (int) gv.db.insertLoginLogInfo(u, 1000);

            return true;
        } else
            exists = false;
    }

    return exists;
        }
    }
```

Then This is my POSContext(DB Context Class):

```
    package com.maziz.POS;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class POSContext extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        //The Android's default system path of your application database.
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.maziz.POS/databases/";

        private static String DB_NAME = "AndroidPOS.sqlite";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

        private final Context myContext;

        /**
         * Constructor
                 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
         * @param context
 */
        public POSContext(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

      /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
```

/*      SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

```
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;*/
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
   // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
   // to you to create adapters for your views.

public Cursor getUser(String uID)
{
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query(true, "FA_Login", new String[] { 
            "PK_FA_Login", "Airline_ID", "Employee_ID", "Password"},
            "Employee_ID = '" + uID + "'", null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getAirportCodes()
{
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Airport_Codes", new String[] { 
            "Airport_Code"
    }, null, null, null, null, "Airport_Code");

    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getFlightByOriginDestination(String origin, String dest)
{
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Inventory_Flight_Schedule", new String[] {
            "PK_Inventory_Flight_Schedule", "Flight_Number", "AC_Type", "Time", "Origin", "Destination"
    }, "Origin = '" + origin + "' AND Destination = '" + dest + "'", null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getFlightByFlightNumber(String fn)
{
    if(fn.equals(""))
        fn = "0";

    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Inventory_Flight_Schedule", new String[] {
            "PK_Inventory_Flight_Schedule", "Flight_Number", "AC_Type", "Time", "Origin", "Destination"
    }, "Flight_Number = " + fn, null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getProductsOnFlight(int pk)
{       
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Inventory_Scheduled", new String[] {
            "PK_Product_ID", "Quantity"
    }, "PK_Inventory_Flight_Schedule = " + pk, null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;
}

public String getProductCategory(int pk)
{       
    String c = "";
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Product_Category_Assigned", new String[] {
            "PK_Product_ID", "PK_Category_ID"
    }, "PK_Product_ID = " + pk, null, null, null, null);

    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        c = c + " " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Category_Name"));
    }

    return c;
}

public Cursor getProductDetailsByProductID(int pID)
{
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query("Products", new String[] {
            "Product_Description", "Product_Name", "Price", "ImageUri"
    }, "PK_Product_ID = " + pID, null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;
}

public ArrayList<Product> getProductSalesDetail(int pkss)
{
    ArrayList<Product> productSales = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product temp;

    Cursor p = myDataBase.query("Sales_Details", new String[] {
            "PK_Product_ID", "Quantity"
    }, "PK_Sales_Summary = " + pkss, null, null, null, null);

    while(p.moveToNext())
    {
        int pkproduct = Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("PK_Product_ID")));
        Cursor product = getProductDetailsByProductID(pkproduct);
        product.moveToFirst();

        temp = new Product();
        temp.PK_Product_ID = pkproduct;
        temp.QuantityInCart = Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("Quantity")));

        temp.Product_Name = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("Product_Name"));
        temp.Price = product.getDouble(product.getColumnIndex("Price"));
        temp.ImageUri = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("ImageUri"));
        productSales.add(temp);
    }

    return productSales;
}

public ArrayList<Product> getProductSales(ArrayList<Integer> pkss)
{
    ArrayList<Product> productSales = new ArrayList<Product>();


    for(int pk: pkss)
    {
        Cursor p = myDataBase.query("Sales_Details", new String[] {
                "PK_Product_ID", "Quantity"
        }, "PK_Sales_Summary = " + pk, null, null, null, null);

        while(p.moveToNext())
        {
            int pkproduct = Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("PK_Product_ID")));
            Cursor product = getProductDetailsByProductID(pkproduct);
            product.moveToFirst();
            Product temp;

            if(productSales.isEmpty())
            {
                temp = new Product();
                temp.PK_Product_ID = pkproduct;
                temp.Quantity = Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("Quantity")));

                temp.Product_Name = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("Product_Name"));
                temp.Price = product.getDouble(product.getColumnIndex("Price"));
                temp.ImageUri = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("ImageUri"));
                productSales.add(temp);
            }
            else   //if product list is not empty
            {
                temp = new Product();
                boolean inList = false;
                for(Product pp: productSales)
                {
                    if(pp.PK_Product_ID == pkproduct)
                    {
                        inList = true;
                        temp.Quantity = temp.Quantity + Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("Quantity")));
                        break;
                    }
                }   

                if(!inList)
                {
                    temp.PK_Product_ID = pkproduct;
                    temp.Quantity = Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("Quantity")));
                    temp.Product_Name = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("Product_Name"));
                    temp.Price = product.getDouble(product.getColumnIndex("Price"));
                    temp.ImageUri = product.getString(product.getColumnIndex("ImageUri"));
                    productSales.add(temp);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < productSales.size(); i++)
                    {
                        Product pp = productSales.get(i);
                        if(pp.PK_Product_ID == pkproduct)
                        {
                            productSales.get(i).Quantity = productSales.get(i).Quantity + Integer.parseInt(p.getString(p.getColumnIndex("Quantity")));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return productSales;
}

public ArrayList<SalesTransaction> getSalesData(int FlightNumber, String currentDate)
{

    Cursor salesData;
    ArrayList<Integer> pkflights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<SalesTransaction> st = new ArrayList<SalesTransaction>();
    currentDate = currentDate.trim();
    String select = "Select PK_Flight_Selected From Flight_Selected Where Flight_Number = '" + FlightNumber + "'";
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(select, null);

            /*myDataBase.query("Flight_Selected", new String[] {
            "PK_Flight_Selected"
    }, "Flight_Number = " + FlightNumber + " AND Flight_Date = '" + currentDate + "'", null, null, null, null);
    */
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        pkflights.add(Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("PK_Flight_Selected"))));
    }

    for(int i: pkflights)
    {
        salesData = myDataBase.query("Sales_Summary", new String[] {
                "PK_Sales_Summary", "PK_Flight_Selected", "Employee_ID", "Total_Items", "Total_Amount"
        }, "PK_Flight_Selected = " + i , null, null, null, null);

        while(salesData.moveToNext())
        {
            SalesTransaction temp = new SalesTransaction();
            temp.PK_Sales_Summary = Integer.parseInt(salesData.getString(salesData.getColumnIndex("PK_Sales_Summary")));
            temp.PK_Flight_Selected = Integer.parseInt(salesData.getString(salesData.getColumnIndex("PK_Flight_Selected")));
            temp.EmployeeID = salesData.getString(salesData.getColumnIndex("Employee_ID"));
            temp.items = Integer.parseInt(salesData.getString(salesData.getColumnIndex("Total_Items")));
            temp.amount = Double.parseDouble(salesData.getString(salesData.getColumnIndex("Total_Amount")));

            Cursor salest = myDataBase.query("Sales_Transactions", new String[] {
                    "PK_Sales_Transaction", "CC_Name"
            }, "PK_Sales_Summary = " + temp.PK_Sales_Summary, null, null, null, null);

            while(salest.moveToNext())
            {
                temp.PK_Sales_Transaction = Integer.parseInt(salest.getString(salest.getColumnIndex("PK_Sales_Transaction")));
                temp.CC_Name = salest.getString(salest.getColumnIndex("CC_Name"));
            }

            st.add(temp);
        }
    }

    return st;
}

public long insertFlightSelectedRecord(int airline_ID, int flight_Number, String o, String d, String fd, String ac)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("Airline_ID", airline_ID);
    cv.put("Flight_Number", flight_Number);
    cv.put("Origin", o);
    cv.put("Dest", d);
    cv.put("Flight_Date", fd.toString());
    cv.put("AC_Type", ac);

    return myDataBase.insert("Flight_Selected", null, cv);
}

public long insertLoginLogInfo(String e, int device)
{

    Date date = new Date();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("Employee_ID", e);
    cv.put("Login_TimeStamp", date.toString());
    cv.put("Device_ID", device);

    return myDataBase.insert("FA_Login_Log", null, cv);
}

public long insertSalesSummary(int pk_flight, String EmployeeID, double total_items, double Amount)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("PK_Flight_Selected", pk_flight);
    cv.put("Employee_ID", EmployeeID);
    cv.put("Total_Items", total_items);
    cv.put("Total_Amount", Amount);

    return myDataBase.insert("Sales_Summary", null, cv);
}

public long insertSalesDetails(int pk_salessummary, int pID, int q)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("PK_Sales_Summary", pk_salessummary);
    cv.put("PK_Product_ID", pID);
    cv.put("Quantity", q);

    return myDataBase.insert("Sales_Details", null, cv);
}

public long insertSalesTransaction(int pkss, double amount, String cctype, String ccnumber, int cccode, String ccName)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("PK_Sales_Summary", pkss);
    cv.put("Amount", amount);
    cv.put("CC_Type", cctype);
    cv.put("CC_Number", ccnumber);
    cv.put("CC_Code", cccode);
    cv.put("CC_Name", ccName);

    return myDataBase.insert("Sales_Transactions", null, cv);
}

public boolean updateLoginLog(int pk, int pkflight)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("PK_Flight_Selected", pkflight);
    return myDataBase.update("FA_Login_Log", cv, "PK_FA_Login_Log = " + pk, null) > 0;
}

    }
```

The error seems to be occurring in the getAirportCode method in POSContext.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:

after further debugging I installed Catlog and this is the error in real time:

```
    03-23 12:34:12.468 I/ActivityManager(1296): Start proc com.maziz.POS for activity com.maziz.POS/.Login: pid=6250 uid=10051 gids={3003}
    03-23 12:34:12.546 I/Database(6250): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 3 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.maziz.POS/databases/AndroidPOS.sqlite-wal
    03-23 12:34:12.546 E/Database(6250): sqlite_prepare_v2(handle, "pragma journal_mode=WAL;") failed for "/data/data/com.maziz.POS/databases/AndroidPOS.sqlite"
    03-23 12:34:12.554 E/Database(6250):    at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.openDataBase(POSContext.java:135)
    03-23 12:34:12.554 E/Database(6250):    at com.maziz.POS.GlobalVars.onCreate(GlobalVars.java:32)
    03-23 12:34:12.562 W/System.err(6250):  at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.openDataBase(POSContext.java:135)
    03-23 12:34:12.562 W/System.err(6250):  at com.maziz.POS.GlobalVars.onCreate(GlobalVars.java:32)
    03-23 12:34:12.625 D/BugSenseHandler(6250): Looking for exceptions in: /data/data/com.maziz.POS/files
    03-23 12:34:12.656 D/BugSenseHandler(6250): Transmitting stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maziz.POS/com.maziz.POS.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-23 12:34:12.656 D/BugSenseHandler(6250):     at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.getAirportCodes(POSContext.java:178)
    03-23 12:34:12.656 D/BugSenseHandler(6250):     at com.maziz.POS.Login.onCreate(Login.java:29)
    03-23 12:34:14.648 D/BugSenseHandler(6250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maziz.POS/com.maziz.POS.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-23 12:34:14.648 D/BugSenseHandler(6250):     at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.getAirportCodes(POSContext.java:178)
    03-23 12:34:14.648 D/BugSenseHandler(6250):     at com.maziz.POS.Login.onCreate(Login.java:29)
    03-23 12:34:14.648 E/AndroidRuntime(6250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maziz.POS/com.maziz.POS.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-23 12:34:14.648 E/AndroidRuntime(6250):      at com.maziz.POS.POSContext.getAirportCodes(POSContext.java:178)
    03-23 12:34:14.648 E/AndroidRuntime(6250):      at com.maziz.POS.Login.onCreate(Login.java:29)
    03-23 12:34:15.492 W/ActivityManager(1296):   Force finishing activity com.maziz.POS/.Login
    03-23 12:34:16.000 W/ActivityManager(1296): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{407109b8 com.maziz.POS/.Login}
    03-23 12:34:17.320 I/ActivityManager(1296): Process com.maziz.POS (pid 6250) has died.
    03-23 12:34:17.718 E/AnrParser(1432): Deleted file/data/anr/anrlogs/ANR_com.maziz.POS_20120323-123414.log
    03-23 12:34:17.718 E/AnrParser(1432): Deleted file/data/anr/anrlogs/com.maziz.POS-logcat.log
    03-23 12:34:26.148 W/ActivityManager(1296): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{407109b8 com.maziz.POS/.Login}
```

Comment: Did you try, you know, debugging? A NullPointerException usually means that you're calling methods on an object variable that hasn't been initialized properly (i. e. contains null). You can debug on your device, just plug it in with a USB cable.

Comment: Yes I am doing that, but it doesn't make sense to me that its working on my emulator but not on my device. I just edited my post with a new logcat copy and what I see now is that its failing to open the DB but still no luck.. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Have you done a full uninstall from the emulator and reinstalled it and it doesn't crash still?

Comment: See below the stack trace in LogCat, the lines that you have not pasted. There's sometimes a "caused by" section which gives you a stack trace of another exception, this time with line numbers and file names in your project (as opposed to the system).

Comment: Ya I looked there too it seems to be the creation of the DB. Idk what the problem is! Ahh 2 days no sleep!

Answer (score 0):

The only object that can generate a NullPointerException in getAirportCodes is myDataBase. You should check in openDataBase if the file really exists. I also noticed you are having a constant for database path. Maybe that is not correct on your device.

To check for your application's database path use getDatabasePath, see link bellow.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)

Comment: I changed it to use getDatabasePath and yet still no go. This is soo weird. Its running perfectly on the emulator yet on the device its giving me these errors. I have also wiped the emulator free of any apps I have developed as well as their data.

Comment: Could it be that my DB is 1.21MB and Assets folder is about 30MB?

Comment: What is printed if you use ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath() ? I'm expecting to be different from your constant DB_PATH + DB_NAME.

Comment: I'm using this.myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath() instead of ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath() because I get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDatabasePath(String) from the type ContextWrapper"  when I use the absolute path method. And the result is: exactly the same! ARGHHH